# How to change the X-axis from milliseconds into hours in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some data measured every 500 milliseconds, you can see my data in the following image:

[image]

Now what I would like to do, is to convert the X-axis into hours instead of milliseconds. How can I do this in Matlab? How can do this generally if I want for example minutes? days? etc.

Thank you for your help =)

Comment: Instead of simply converting ms to hours by dividing by ``1000*3600`` you should also have a look at matlabs ``datetick`` and ``datenum`` / ``datetime`` functions for plotting timeseries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that's pretty easy. Assume your vector is `time_ms`, to get it in hours, you just need:

```
time_h = time_ms/(1000*3600);
```

Then instead of doing something like:

```
plot(time_ms,my_data)
```

Just do:

```
plot(time_h,my_data)
```

Comment: Should you not divide by `3600*1000`?

Comment: @rayryeng Oops, you're right of course, will update answer & comment

Comment: lol no problem.  I was double-checking... which is why I asked the question! I wanted to be sure that I got the logic straight.  +1 of course.

Comment: But of course x) Thank you for your help, I thought at first I needed to edit the XTick or something :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have 100 data collected every 500 ms and you simply rescale the X axis to hours, you'll still get 100 data but as they had been collected every hour.

For example, suppose you have 3600 data collected every second.

```
data = rand(1,3600); 
time_s = 1:3600;
```

Now, suppose you want to plot the data every minute. Without any processing, you could get every 60th sample in the `data` array.

```
data_m = data(1:60:3600);
time_m = 1:60;
```

Doing this way, you'll get a consistent plot.

(I'd attach images but I lack reputation)